# How to Convert Byte[] to Image in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

```
public System.Drawing.Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    System.Drawing.Image returnImage = null;

    try
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms); // parameter is invalid

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string a = ex.ToString();
        // Response.Write("sfdsfn");
    }

    return returnImage;
}
```

I did lot of search in Net but i cant get any useful answer for me?
any help..thanks in advance

Comment: Given that your question is about ASP.NET, how do you intend to use your `Image`? You cannot simply put it in an `<asp:Image>` element, if that's what you were thinking, and the alternative use I can come up with does not require a conversion to `System.Drawing.Image`. What is your end goal?

Comment: What do you mean by parameter is invalid? Can you post the exception you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

Simple way [`Image.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx):

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] imgBytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream(imgBytes))
    {
        return Image.FromStream(imgStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`new Bitmap(ms)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw.aspx):

```
Image returnImage = null;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
returnImage = new Bitmap(ms);
```

Similarly, you can use `Bitmap.FromStream` (oddly, I can't find documentation for it).

Comment: It's [`Image.FromStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx), but `Bitmap.FromStream` will work as `Bitmap` derives from `Image`.

Comment: @hvd - good point. Still, I expect to find it on [Bitmap Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap_methods.aspx) - there are other inherited members. Oh well. Anyway, that also suggests the OP's code should work.

Comment: Inherited instance members are listed, but I think it depends on the language whether static members of base classes are accessible in the derived class, and the documentation is for .NET, not C# specifically. I do agree that the current situation, where `Bitmap.FromStream` compiles but is hard to look up, leaves room for improvement. :)

Answer (score -1):

Took me 2 minutes to find this one :

```
ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
Image img = (Image)ic.ConvertFrom(byteArray);
```